# Filtering Characters in HTML - Python - Django

Tags: python, html, django, parsing, filter

So I am building a website and needed to be able to filter by a prefix on a model field I have in Django on my website. Now when I display this I need the prefix to be gone. The simplest way to do this seems to be in the HTML itself with something that says to not include the first 4 characters or before such as [4:]. This seems simple but I can't get it to work and I can get this to work

```
|truncatechars:"10"
```

which was a recommended solution. I need something in either my views or in my HTML that says when you print don't display the first 4 characters but display everything beyond that. Thanks for any help!

HTML:

```
{{ form.title }}
```

Models:

```
class DocPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=True, related_name="Doc", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = HTMLField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pk']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('doc-post-list')
```

Django Views:

```
def docpostnewview(request, pk):

    obj = get_object_or_404(DocPost, id=pk)

    form = DocPostForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/" + id)

    context = {"form":form}

    #context['title'] = DocPost.objects.all().filter(title='title')

    return render(request, "my_app/use_template.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cut filter as below it will display title skipping "Temp:" substring.Remember this will Removes all values of "Temp:" from the given title.

```
{{ form.title|cut:"Temp:" }}
```

Comment: unfortunate this didnt work. The only thing displayed on the screen are these two characters. []

Comment: whats the value of {{form.title}} ?

Comment: It's an input of text so for instance I have this as the value right now "Temp: Testing" or it could be this "Temp: T12345". The important thing is that they all start with "Temp: " and I need that to be gone when it's displayed.

Comment: try cut filter but remember its case sensitive {{ form.title|cut:"Temp:" }}

Comment: Awsome, THanks it worked like a charm. If you want to put up another post with this info I can accept it so others can find this answer easier. Thanks!

Comment: @RussellHertel : Have edited answer as per your requirements kindly accept if same worked.